# RabbitMQ + dead letter exchange and autodelete

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there an option, to autodelete a queue if a dead-letter-exchange occurs?

I'm creating something like a scheduled tasks.

Eg:

1. I create a base worker-queue
2. then create helper queues with dead-letter-exchange
3. It routes the messages correctly to worker.

Now how to tell RabbitMQ to delete helper queues after they're used? Or do I have to delete them manually (using an another "garbage-collector" queue, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x-expires: <ms>
```

Is the solution. D'oh.